# Как в шаблоне opencart проверять логическую переменную?

Tags: opencart

Как в Opencart проверять переменную $logged в шаблон column_right.tpl?

Comment: вопрос нужно перефразировать. "в шаблон column_right" - бессмысленное уточнение, а вот тип переменной было бы полезно указать (boolean?), хотя подозреваю, что вам и более общая конструкция подойдёт. А что там за шаблонизатор в opencart?

Comment: Шаблонизатора, как такового нет, просто php.

Answer (score 0):

В контроллер `catalog/controller/common/column_right.php` добавить:

```
$this->data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
```

В шаблоне `catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/column_right.tpl`:

```
<?php if ($logged) { ?>
   Что будет для покупателей.
<?php } else { ?>
   Что будет для гостей.
<?php } ?>
```